# DB2 HADR Sync mode different on primary and standby server

Tags: db2, database-replication, db2-luw

When using HADR do both the primary and standby need to be in same sync mode? 
What could be the possible outcomes if both are not same.

Answer (score 0):

The synchronization mode determines when the primary database server considers a transaction complete, based on the state of the logging on the standby database.

So what sync mode you have on standby system does not matter. When this standby becomes new primary after failover, it will use local value of SYNCMODE for synchronisation.

Comment: I have a case where the customer has Primary in ASYNC and Standby in SYNC mode. So there would not be any problem while taking takeover?

Comment: You should be able to takeover but your takeover options are limited based on the mode. If the current Primary is ASYNC then you don't get peer window options for example.  Once you do a takeover on the Standby and it becomes the primary, then you will have presumably a synchronous standby (the old primary) and will have peer options.

Here is a link to a best practice document for HADR setups
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Wc9a068d7f6a6_4434_aece_0d297ea80ab1/page/High%20Availability%20Disaster%20Recovery